# two UINavigationControllers in same viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I got some issue working with `UINavigationalControllers` for iPad.

Issue :

`UINavigationController1`
`UINavigationController2`

Placed in `UIViewController`.

When the event happened in `UINavigationController1`....the action should be taken in `UINavigationController2`

Something like this..... When Click happened on `UITableViewCell` in `UINavigationController1`, the transition between view should be done in `UINavigationController2`

Need some suggestion how to handle this ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use delegate for the same. Create custom delegate for view controller and handle action. May it help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use delegation to do this

add this in the .h of ViewController1 above the @implementation

```
@protocol ViewController1Delegate;
```

and then this below the @end

```
@protocol ViewController1Delegate <NSObject>

- (void)viewController1:(id)controller didDoAction;

@end
```

then declare a property of type ViewController1Delegate in the controller

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <ViewController1Delegate> delegate;
```

then add this to the .m of ViewController1

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

and on the action call the delegate method

```
if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(viewController1:didDoAction)]) {
    [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(viewController1:didDoAction) withObject:self];
}
```

Now when on ViewController2 .h impot ViewController1.h

```
#import ViewController1.h
```

Now when on ViewController2 .h listen for the delegate like this

```
@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController <ViewController1Delegate>
```

and then in the .m implement the method

```
- (void)viewController1:controller didDoAction
{
  //implement
}
```

when the view controllers are instantiated one needs to set the delegate for viewController1 to viewController2 like this

```
viewController1 = [ViewController1 new];
viewController2 = [ViewController2 new];
viewController1.delegate = viewController2
```